# How to run my python files as testcases using Robotframework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have automated my window app using python library called pywinauto. I have a set of python files, each files will handle each functionalities. I want to create the testcases using these python modules and run it sequentially. how can i do it using Robotframework? i have the setup ready. But don't know how to proceed.

Comment: It would help if you can post a small example of what it is you want to achieve or work with. This will help in generating specific answers, or allows those that have already answered to tailor their examples to your specific situation.

Answer (score 4):

You choose one of your Python files to be the keywords library for Robot Framework. If it's a class, its public methods will be the keywords you use from Robot Framework test cases. See the example at the beginning of [4.1 Creating test libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#creating-test-libraries) in the User Guide.

Then you write a `.robot` file with the Robot Framework syntax to execute your test. You import your Python keywords into that with the `Library` setting or the `Import Library` keyword.

For example, if your Python class using pywinauto has the methods `click_on_button(self, button_caption)`, your `.robot` file could be something like:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     your_python_filename

*** Test Cases***
Test Case Name
    Click on button    Button Caption here
```

Comment: i will try this and get back to you. Thanks for the help.